# html fileupload control doesnt upload file in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, file-upload

I have an asp.net application with a page to upload files (csv file). In this page I have an updatepanel in that I have a html fileupload control.
The fileupload works fine with both IE and Firefox.  With chrome, I can see the PostedFile.Filename = "bac.csv", 
PostedFile.InputStream.Length = 80 
But when I copy the Inputstream to a byte array, all the bytes have zero value. Remember this same code works fine with other browsers.

Fiddler also shows different postdata. see below for Chrome and Firefox data that I see in Fiddler. Clearly, Chrome is not posting the file data.  What I am doing wrong and how can I fix it.

## Chorme data

```
POST http://nap1557pdv:8081/Test.aspx HTTP/1.1 
Host: nap1557pdv:8081 
Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Length: 1080 
Cache-Control: max-age=0 
Authorization: Negotiate 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 
Origin: http://nap1557pdv:8081 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryoVCxaJFfHyYJTJUZ 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 
Referer: http://nap1557pdv:8081/Test.aspx 
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8 
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3 
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=tprepknwc3ejjfvmvewhb3ea 

------WebKitFormBoundaryoVCxaJFfHyYJTJUZ 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl07_HiddenField" 


------WebKitFormBoundaryoVCxaJFfHyYJTJUZ 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTTARGET" 


------WebKitFormBoundaryoVCxaJFfHyYJTJUZ 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTARGUMENT" 


------WebKitFormBoundaryoVCxaJFfHyYJTJUZ 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATE" 

/wEPZwUPOGNmMDIzYmE5MWZmZTE3yZ1szJcaImr6jsC8aAj3Jr/NJZHuYmM9v1nicrGvr1I= 
------WebKitFormBoundaryoVCxaJFfHyYJTJUZ 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTVALIDATION" 

/wEWAgKZhrWmDwLAtdSqDb+OpffaxhvDEvRAly4rTIajFqtN7G6bde9qDsAeL/uL 
------WebKitFormBoundaryoVCxaJFfHyYJTJUZ 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl00$MainContent$fileUploadChartData"; filename="bac.csv" 
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel 

???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????? 
------WebKitFormBoundaryoVCxaJFfHyYJTJUZ 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl00$MainContent$btnUploadDocument" 

Upload 
------WebKitFormBoundaryoVCxaJFfHyYJTJUZ--
```

## Firefox Data

```
POST http://nap1557pdv:8081/Test.aspx HTTP/1.1 
Host: nap1557pdv:8081 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 
Connection: keep-alive 
Referer: http://nap1557pdv:8081/Test.aspx 
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=i2egjzbii2d4ttz4uhripgz4 
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------24464570528145 
Content-Length: 1104 

-----------------------------24464570528145 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl07_HiddenField" 


-----------------------------24464570528145 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTTARGET" 


-----------------------------24464570528145 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTARGUMENT" 


-----------------------------24464570528145 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATE" 

/wEPZwUPOGNmMDIzYzRlZjk0NDk3xSjtNc5KxDS+sptXgXIwFbIwfngQQcicVPd0sZS0Hes= 
-----------------------------24464570528145 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTVALIDATION" 

/wEWAgKes7e9AgLAtdSqDeYF8SG+RG8hp8rFuJK7HrsxNq8TZlkf0m0bUTEzK9Pq 
-----------------------------24464570528145 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl00$MainContent$fileUploadChartData"; filename="bac.csv" 
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel 

Symbol,Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume 
BAC,4/25/2012,8.21,8.35,8.19,8.23,563453 
-----------------------------24464570528145 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl00$MainContent$btnUploadDocument" 

Upload 
-----------------------------24464570528145--
```

Comment: I want to provide more info on this problem.  I observed that this happens when the IIS security is set to "Windows Authentication" only.  If I enable "Anonymous Authentication" or both it works fine.   I cannot enable "Anonymous Authentication" for this web page.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem with Windows Authentication. Unfortunately, I have to use Windows Auth for this application.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue in Chrome 19.0.1084.46. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128574

Answer (score 2):

We have exactly the same behaviour (jpeg files containing only NUL values)
We are using IIS webservers with windows authentication and Chrome 19.0.1084.46.
It was introduced tuesday when Google updated chrome..

For now we reverted to using MSIE9